# PyQt5 treeview with multiple columns how to get info into other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, treeview, pyqt5

I am trying to create a tree view in nPyQt5 and I would like to have have the list item as well as the data type and length in the tree, the parent of the tree will not have this information. 
I have the tree working but everything is in one column in the tree and I would like to add information to the other 2 columns.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication,QFileDialog,QAbstractItemView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel,QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from treeview import *
import lxml.etree as etree

features = {('POLYGON', 'SLPR'): [('ONE WAY', ['NO', 'YES'], 'List', 3), ('CLASS', ['INTERSTATE', 'PRIMARY', 'RESIDENTIAL', 'SECONDARY', 'SERVICE', 'STATE HWY', 'TERTIARY', 'TRACK', 'US HWY'], 'List', 11)], ('POINT', 'CALC FLD'): [('NAME', [], 'TEXT', '50'), ('SURFACE', ['BLACK TOP', 'BRICK', 'CALICHE', 'CALICHE AND GRAVEL', 'CINDER', 'CONCRETE', 'DIRT', 'GRASS', 'GRAVEL', 'LIMESTONE', 'OILED', 'PAVED ASPHALT', 'ROCK', 'SAND', 'SAND AND GRAVEL', 'SCORIA', 'SHELL', 'SHELL & OIL', 'SLAG'], 'List', 18)], ('POINT', 'RKDH'): [('TYPE', ['COUNTY', 'DO NOT USE', 'ENGINEERED', 'IMPROVED', 'PRIMITIVE', 'TEMPLATE', 'TEMPORARY ACCESS'], 'List', 16)]}
class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButtonFile.clicked.connect(self.dispFolder)
        self.ui.pushButtonLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadXml)
        self.show()
    def dispFolder(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Open File','/home')
        if fname[0]:
            self.ui.lineEditFile.setText(fname[0])
    def loadXml(self):
        print(features)
        model = QStandardItemModel(0,3,self.ui.treeView)
        model.setHeaderData(0,Qt.Horizontal,"CODE")
        model.setHeaderData(1,Qt.Horizontal,"DATA TYPE")
        model.setHeaderData(2,Qt.Horizontal,"LENGTH")
        self.ui.treeView.setModel(model)
        i=0
        for k,featuretype in features.items():
            parent1 = QStandardItem('{}'.format(k[1]))
            for item in featuretype:
                child = QStandardItem(item[0])
                if len(item[1])>0:
                    for listitem in item[1]:
                        gchild=QStandardItem(listitem)
                        child.appendRow(gchild)
                parent1.appendRow(child)
            model.setItem(i,0,parent1)
            self.ui.treeView.setFirstColumnSpanned(i,self.ui.treeView.rootIndex(),True)
            i+=1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is my treeview.py which has the ui I created in Designer

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButtonFile = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButtonFile.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 20, 75, 23))
        self.pushButtonFile.setObjectName("pushButtonFile")
        self.lineEditFile = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEditFile.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 231, 20))
        self.lineEditFile.setObjectName("lineEditFile")
        self.pushButtonLoad = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButtonLoad.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 250, 75, 23))
        self.pushButtonLoad.setObjectName("pushButtonLoad")
        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(Dialog)
        self.treeView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 50, 256, 192))
        self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButtonFile.setText(_translate("Dialog", "File"))
        self.pushButtonLoad.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Load"))
```

[image]

So for POINT the DATA TYPE is double and the LENGTH would be  None, LOCATION would be LIST DATA TYPE and the LENGTH would be the field length

All of that information is in the features dictionary which is a piece of an xml conversion I pieced together. The list in the dictionary is actually an xml element in the original piece of code.

Comment: Do you mean that for each child of the root it should have the data "type" and count, instead of the actual items of the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the standard item model is instantiated with 3 columns the rows can be appended with an item or item(s) so

```
parent1.appendRow([item1,item2,item3])
```

will populate all 3 columns, to populate a second column for the parent simply set the item in the model at the desired index

```
model.setItem(row,col,item)
```

[image]